# .htaccess not running mod-rewrite or not being executed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have an .htaccess set to permissions 777 with a simple rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I've deleted all of the  commands except a simplified:

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf, I've added:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride All
  Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've also "sudo service apache2 restart"   (Ubuntu 14.04)

But for whatever reason, I can't get calls to http://www.myserver.com/blah/blah to be routed to index.php

It feels like the .htaccess is being ignored or the rewrite rule isn't running.

I'm out of ideas on where to look and I've followed the other SO posts without luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava Tebro figured it out, below.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the rewrite module turned on.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Since you have the if check for the module that means that there wont be any errors if it is not enabled.

Comment: Gosh darn it, I knew I forgot something.  :)  Thanks Tebro!  BTW, can you correct your answer?  It is "sudo a2enmod rewrite"